# Use of default alias "alert"

Tags: bash, notification

The default alias ***Alert*** is for the command

```
notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"
```

Executing `alert` gives an notification with text **Alert** and an terminal icon.
Executing it with one param like `alert !!!!!` gives notification with text **Alert !!!!!** and **!!!!!**.

So, what's the difference between simple `notify-send` command and this complexed  alias which uses *notify-send, echo, history, tail and sed*?

In which situations is this alias useful or was it just created for pun(Something like using `sudo sudo sudo sudo sudo apt-get install`

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: The only thing I can think of is just to make creating a notification easier...maybe?

Comment: @saiarcot895 try `notify-send Linux Ubuntu` it's much the same, the only difference is that `alert` shows a icon.But I don't understand why the command contains sed,tail and history

Comment: For a detailed breakdown of how this works, see:
https://saddlebackcss.github.io/tutorials/bash/2016/01/20/how-bash-alert-works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the man pages to get details about what the commands combined here do. Here's a little about the purpose of those commands here:

```
"$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)"
```

This would echo *terminal* or *error* as per to the execution status - *successful* or *fail* respectively of the last command; and the result is as the value to the `-i` switch of `notify-send` for displaying the icons.

```
history|tail -n1
```

..to get the last command executed.

and `sed` to parse the text to display it with `notify-send` message.

---

**To understand these try the following:**

```
true; echo "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)"
```

..this would echo *terminal*.

```
false; echo "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)"
```

..this would echo *error*.

```
notify-send -i terminal 'Please note the icon..' 'the default icon for the terminal has been used. You can specify any other icon of your choice'
```

And,

```
echo $?
```

..is very useful to know the exit value of the last command executed.

```
echo "$(echo "the output of this command enclosed within \$(...)") is being supplied here in the outer echo command where is used as an argument."
```

..nested `echo` as a simple demo for using `$()` in a command combo.

Comment: so this alias can be used to tell the user whether the command executed successfully or failed, but in an GUI way.

Comment: yes it would notify about both the successful or unsuccessful executions graphically using the `notify-send`.. the exit status of last command is checked with the value of `$?`..I've included this in the edit..

Answer (score 7):

Let me try to explain what is happening here:

```
notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"
```

- `--urgency=low`

  > ```
  > -u, --urgency=LEVEL Specifies the urgency level (low, normal, critical).
  > ```
- `-i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)"`

  > ```
  > -i, --icon=ICON[,ICON...]
  >       Specifies an icon filename or stock icon to display.
  > ```

  This part `"$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)"`. `$?` is the last error (or success) returned. So it returns text "terminal" if last command exit code was 0, without errors. Or returns "error" if exit code was not 0.

  And finally we get "terminal" or "error" icon.
- `$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')`

  `history|tail -n1` returns the last command from history.

  `sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')` this can be separated in 2 block of sed.
- `sed 's/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//'` remove all preceding spaces and tabs, all numerical after that, and also remove spaces and tabs at the end.
- `s/[;&|]\s*alert$//` removes preceding symbols `;` `&` `|`, any tabs and spaces and word "alert".

  It is just clean last executed command from symbols, and the word "alert" at the end.

  So if you use something like this:

  ```
  echo "Hello alert" | alert
  ```

  It will show alert with previous command.

Answer (score 4):

I think the current answers explain **how** the inner workings of alert work (which is what I wanted to find out of curiosity and which got me here). But I think the original OP asks for **what** it is useful for which I'll try to explain as I understand from the commends above its declaration.

It is basically used to alert you when a command has finished when you can't sit watching the terminal the whole time waiting for it to finish. As per the commend example `sleep 10; alert` will show a notification of the command (`sleep 10` in this case) with a terminal icon if it is successful (sleep 10 will take 10 seconds to complete).

From this you can see that it should be used as `<command>; alert` where you replace command with your command. I personally have to download a video everyday via wget because it fails periodically. So I just append the download command with alert to immediately notify me when it failed so that it can be continued again (my alert is modified to also beep to get my attention).

Answer (score 0):

The reason `sed`, `tail`, and `history` are there is because it needs to get the message that you typed. (For some reason,) what you typed isn't directly available through any variable. Therefore, it has to use `history` to get the list of everything you've typed, `tail -n1` to get the last thing you typed, and some regex to get rid of the "alert" command at the start.

Just to expand on this, there is a conditional command in there that tests to see if `$? = 0` is true. From what I can tell, if it is true, then it is coming from the terminal, and should be regarded as a normal message. Otherwise, it should be considered an error, and an error icon will appear.

Comment: It doesn't get rid of **alert**, it will remain in the notification.

Comment: If you answer with "for some reason" it is often not a very good answer ;)

Comment: @Requist: I added "for some reason" for that specific statement because I was under the impression that `$0` gives you the first argument for a command. It might be different in the case of an alias, though.