# Modify the "alert" alias in ~/.bashrc

Tags: command-line, bash, notification

**System: Lubuntu 14.04 LTS**

I want to know if it's possible to modify the `alert` alias provided in `~/.bashrc` in a particular way. This is the original `alert`:

```
# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'
```

[Use of default alias “alert”](https://askubuntu.com/q/423646/248158) explains what it does.

And here is an example of the default notification on my system (using `xfce4-notify`) when I run `ls; alert` which, of course, completes successfully:

[image: 01Default-alert]

If I run a nonsensical command, `asdfgh; alert`, I see this:

[image: 02Nonsense-command]

The `terminal` icon has been replaced with the `error` icon because of

```
-i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)"
```

As of now, the notification has just two items:
  - the icon which is `terminal` or `error` depending on the success of the "previous" command
  - the command itself (`ls` in the first case and `asdfgh` in the second)

I can modify the existing alias to include a line of text **above** the command like this:

```
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "Task finished" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'
```

Then, if I run `ls; alert` and `asdfgh; alert` I get the notifications shown below.

[image: Task finished successfully]

[image: Something went wrong]

My question is this: Both notifications show "Task finished" but can the same logic that is used to decide whether the `terminal` icon or the `error` icon is shown *be applied again* to determine which text string is shown above the command? So, if the `terminal` icon displays, the text would be "Task finished" but if the `error` icon displays, the text could something like "Something went wrong!"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Tl;dr

Use this:

```bsh
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && (echo terminal; exit 0) || (echo error; exit 1))" "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo Task finished || echo Something went wrong!)" "$(history | sed -n "\$s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*\(.*\)[;&|]\s*alert\$/\1/p")"'
```

---

Simply evaluating `$?` again won't work, because by the time `$?` would be evaluated the second time it would contain the first command subsitution's (`$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)`'s) exit status (always `0` since the two `echo`s would always succed). A trick to go around this would be making the first command substitution exit with an equivalent exit status again:

```bsh
$([ $? = 0 ] && (echo terminal; exit 0) || (echo error; exit 1))
```

This way `$?` could be evaluated a second time in order to decide which string to print:

```bsh
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && (echo terminal; exit 0) || (echo error; exit 1))" "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo Task finished || echo Something went wrong!)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'
```

On another note your `history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\''` is a bit over-convoluted. This would be way more readable:

```bsh
history | sed -n "\$s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*\(.*\)[;&|]\s*alert\$/\1/p"
```

So, final command:

```bsh
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && (echo terminal; exit 0) || (echo error; exit 1))" "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo Task finished || echo Something went wrong!)" "$(history | sed -n "\$s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*\(.*\)[;&|]\s*alert\$/\1/p")"'
```

You can test by running `(exit 0); alert` and `(exit 1); alert`.

Comment: @DKBose Sure. Check out the update also, there was a problem with your `sed` command (I should have fixed it).

Comment: @DKBose Right, I see it works for you, however that's weird. Your original alias doesn't work for me if I copy it verbatim (meaning: I get the number before the command). That would be the expected behavior, since GNU `sed` by default interprets patterns as EREs, which require escaping `+`. In fact escaping `+` on your original command works for me. Just curious, which `sed` are you using?

Comment: @DKBose Ah I see the problem: when I answered, I answered [this](http://askubuntu.com/revisions/749202/1) revision. Without the code formatting the `\+` in your modified version was interpreted as an escaped markdown special character and the \ just didn't show up. However I simplified that command a little bit more in case you're interested.