# How can I use the in-built function alert in Gnome Schedule?

Tags: bash, cron, schedule, gnome-schedule

I want to access the [alert](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423646/use-of-default-alias-alert) function in [Gnome Schedule](http://gnome-schedule.sourceforge.net/).

I can run `alert` from my default Bash command-line but receive the following error in Gnome Schedule:

```
/tmp/tmpxi4X16: line 1: alert: command not found
Press ENTER to continue and close this window.
```

The following screenshot illustrates the problem. The visible notification comes from the right terminal window. The left terminal window is the result of me manually running the recurrent task `Mackup` in Gnome Schedule.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into your ~/.bashrc file youll find the alias which defines `alert`.

```
# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'
```

Example:
Try as input in your manual terminal:

```
notify-send "Hello World!"
```