# Something has set up an alias I don't understand "alert"

Tags: alias

When I type in the command `alias` I get some funny things I don't understand:

```
rick@dell:~$ alias
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias l='ls -CF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

The first command / alias seems to do nothing when I type:

```
rick@dell:~$ alert "It's raining"
```

How, where, when and why is this `alert` command supposed to be used in an `alias`?

---

#### Duplicate close thoughts:

The proposed duplicate explains `alert` alias to great extent but doesn't explain why typing `Alert "It's raining"` does NOT result in a notification bubble.

The question above does ask for complete explanation though which the CV duplicate satisfied.

A day after the above question was posted a new Question with "provide your own Answer" option was posted here: ([notify-send (alert) not popping-up GUI bubble messages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/847623/notify-send-alert-not-popping-up-gui-bubble-messages?noredirect=1#comment1302244_847623)) and it solves the reason for posting the above question in the first place.

The above CV candidate question can almost be considered "too broad" because it is seeking advice about aliases AND ~/.bashrc AND notify-send.

I have voted to close this question as a duplicate too.

Comment: See `man notify-send` for clarification on what the alias `alert` is for. Similarly `man ls` will provide clues to what the`l`, `la`, `ll` aliases do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of default alias "alert"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/423646/use-of-default-alias-alert)

Comment: Just for fun try `alert FreeBeer` ;)

Comment: Are you using this on the GUI?

Comment: @muru I don't know how to type a terminal command in the GUI.

Comment: Don't act dumb. Are you running this on a terminal started in the GUI? Or are you on the TTYs or SSH?

Comment: No I'mnot spying on your debit card, @muru I am using it in gnome-terminal (the output is on the GUI)

Comment: I'm not being glib. I've never used SSH and am not using Alt+Ctrl+F1 or whatever the console command is.

Comment: CTRL-ALT-T brings up a terminal in the GUI

Comment: Of course I'm using ctrl, alt, t to invoke the terminal.

Comment: There's no "of course" about it. The alias doesn't seem to be working for you, so now it's a question of debugging it. Then you don't assume anything. As to what it does and how it does what it does, that's adequately explained in the other question.

Comment: IT's not working for him due to the unclosed quote in It's raining

Comment: So I guess it's not a duplicate question after all.... Should I rephrase the question?

Comment: try exactly `alert Itworks`

Comment: It didn't work... but then I normalized the TV screen which was maximized with "Always on top" option and then it did work.

Comment: Thanks Elder.... I'll dig up one of your historical answers and up-vote it :)

Comment: This one is fine. No need to go all historical on me! ;-)

Comment: Too late I +1 the how to backup a desktop answer. I might actually do that some day :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an unclosed quote in `It's raining`. bash is waiting for you to close the quote behind the scenes so it appears it's not working. Try a single word without an apostrophe or even "CamelCase" or close the quote like `alert It's raining'`

Another possibility that might make you think the alert alias isn't working is a window with the always-on-top modifier over the upper right quadrant of your desktop.

Comment: actually the first attempt was "Help Me~~~~" but that didn't work either. As in comment above it was because TV was maximized with "always on top" option, and "normalizing" the window allowed the notification bubble to appear. I did upvote your "How to backup a desktop PC" answer for all your hard work on this topic. Thank you!

Comment: No worries, I enjoyed it!

Comment: A single quote inside double quotes is literal. E.g. run `echo "It's"`

Comment: @wjandrea That's true. I'm not sure why I wasn't `alert` enough to catch that.  ;-)